# Office prevents files from opening through Office URI Schemes on Windows 10

Tags: asp.net, windows, ms-office, blazor-server-side, url-scheme

I would like to allow the user to open a Word file from a Blazor server-side application (ASP .NET)

To do this, I use Office URI Schemes (`ms-word:ofv|u|//...`)

The link works fine, and Office starts, but it refuses to open the file and displays the following message:

[image]

Translation :
*To protect you from unsafe content, Office blocked this file from opening because it came from a site in the Sensitive Area*

How can I bypass this message? I have full access to the machines that will use the application and I can configure Windows on each of them.